# phonetics name of vibration in the wind pipe

Tags: phonetics, voicing

A very angry, sonorant voice may have the vocal lips, wind pipe and whole throat vibrating.

For example, we may see this as phoneme in e.g. imitation of a wolfs growl, "grrr", a game show's bad-answer signal (I'm not aware of a transcription) or a propeller airplane and other motors. As the word "growl" shows, this often sounds like "r" and incorporates the palate (in contrast to h-, "howl"). The airplane noise is often realized without the sought sonorant quality, "neeeeeaouu" but a chainsaw is imitated onomatopoeticly as "runn" or "rrrring", not to be confused with the ring of an old telephone bell. It doesn't appear to be a distinct phone, e.g. in IPA, rather it can modulate any vocal or voiced consonant.

I want to read about it, so I need a search term. What's it called?

Is it a [Voiced Epiglottal Trill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_epiglottal_trill) or a pharyngel?

Edit: **Sound snippets** Death Metal Growling [at 1:07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0QnqgDVC6g), realization of German "R" without trill [around 0:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x_g43elUQo&t=24) (can't understand the word though; with trill at 2:04 "wartes'"), a pirate saying "argh" [0:20 onwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7xftyFjKFc&t=20) (not as approximant), more growling at [6:55](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpMZVu_DCdg&t=414).

Comment: This isn't a language sound and not a phoneme. There are very many ways of growling. Most likely what you are encountering is a uvular, but we'd need direct attestation of what you're talking about.

Comment: My guess is a voiced uvular trill, but the description here isn't precise enough to be sure. Can you be any more precise about this sound?

Comment: @Draconis the recent question about voiced uvular or alveolar trills made me think of it. I wanted to mention the sound in question as another variation of German "R", even without trill.

Comment: I guess "growl" is good enough. The duplicate is not quite the same, as the last three aren't disorders (the first one is indecicive)